# Why did the if statement in the loop not work?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I was scraping Yahoo finance and somehow the `if` condition did not work. What the `if` was supposed to do was to print the stock price if the stock price was greater than 50, but it printed all the stocks which were above 50 and below 50.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

list = ["aapl","goog","yhoo"]
i = 0
while i < len(list):
      url = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ list[i] +"&q1=1")
      soup = bs4(url,"html.parser")
      for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + list[i]}):
           if price > 50:
               print price
               i += 1
           else:
               print "failed"
               1 += 1
```

Why did it print the stock "yahoo", cause "yahoo" is less than 50, no?

Comment: Not a solution, but you have a typo in the last line: `1 += 1`. Should be `i += 1` I think.

Comment: Place `print type(price)` in the `for`loop and give the output of it here please.

Comment: You need to convert the string to a number before performing the comparison. `if int(price) > 50:` (or maybe a float if it's a decimal number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you've mixed types:

> if price > 50:
>
> TypeError: unorderable types: NavigableString() > int()

Use this:

```
if float(price) > 50:
   print price
```

Comment: Why do you make a `float` and then convert it to `int`?

Comment: Then better leave it `float`, because in case of e.g. price = "50.1" there will be wrong output :)

Comment: And you missed a colon after `ìf`

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite code in following:

1. `1 += 1` will not work because LHS should be variable name. This is `i += 1` . this might be typing mistake. :)
2. No need of `i` variable, we can iterate `list` by `for` loop. This will remove our `i += 1` statements from the code.
3. Do not use in-built variable names as our variable names. e.g. `list` is `list type` variable used to create new list. If we use such variable name then this will create problem in code.

**e.g**.

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
>>> a = list()
>>> a
[]
>>> list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a = list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```

4. Use **exception handling** during **Type Casting** means when we convert one data type to other data type.

**Demo**:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

item_list = ["aapl","goog","yhoo"]
target_url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%s&q1=1"
target_id = "yfs_l84_%s"

for i in item_list:
    url = urllib2.urlopen(target_url%i)
    soup = bs4(url, "html.parser")
    for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':target_id%i}):
        try:
            price = float(price)
        except:
            print "Exception during type conversion. Value is %s. Type is %s."%(price, type(price)) 
            continue
        if price > 50:
            print "Price:", price
        else:
            print "failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

`price` is string, you have to convert it to number:

```
   if int(price) > 50:
       print price
       i += 1
   else:
       print "failed"
       i += 1
```

or (with fractional part):

```
   if float(price) > 50:
       print price
       i += 1
   else:
       print "failed"
       i += 1
```